# Query/Expression for Previous Month

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Used as an expression in Access 2010, the below returns, for example, `AUG15`.

```
Left(MonthName(Month(Date())),3) & Right(Year(Date()),2)
```

How do I modify this to return the previous month, i.e. `JUL15`?

Comment: don't forget to select an answer as accepted if they helped solve your issue. Otherwise, please indicate if more help is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the `DateAdd` expression which @Sam suggested ...

```vb
? DateAdd("m", -1, Date())
7/13/2015
```

Next use `Format` to present it as 3-letter month plus 2-digit year ...

```vb
? Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()), "mmmyy")
Jul15
```

If you want the month in all caps, feed the previous expression to `UCase` ...

```vb
? UCase(Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()), "mmmyy"))
JUL15
```

Note those examples are from the Access Immediate window, but those expressions (without `?`) will work the same in your query.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [DateAdd](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateAdd-Function-63befdf6-1ffa-4357-9424-61e8c57afc19) function:

```
DateAdd ( interval, number, date )
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you could use it to substract a month from the current date like so:

```
DateAdd(m, -1, Date())
```

...or to build upon your expression:

```
Left(MonthName(Month(DateAdd(m, -1, Date()))),3) & Right(Year(DateAdd(m, -1, Date())),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

to get records on same day of last month,eg. today is 19/12/21,and get records on 19/11/21 , you can use parameter query and enter the date required.

If every records of last month, ie from 1/11/21 to 30/11/21, two columns in query should be created to identify the month and year required. Make it clear,2 columns in query `m:month(date())` and `y:year(date())` and in criteria row put criteria of month and year required. If for last month criteria for m column is `IIF(month(date())=1,12,month(date())-1)`, for y column is `IIf(month(date())=1,year(date())-1,year(date()))`.
`IIF` is for when current date is in January.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).